# Catch file not found error and continue running the code in python

Tags: python, file, try-catch

I have Ten thousand files in one folder. The file's names are numerically sorted. I am trying to move the files. Some files are already moved to a new folder. I have written the code to move the files but due to some files already being moved to a new folder, the code stops when the number hits the number of the file which has already been moved. I tried using try and catch the exception but it's not working. I would like the code to skip this error and continue moving the files.

This is what I have tired

```
import os, shutil
path = "I:\\"
moveto = "I:\\"
i = 1
j = 1
try:
    while True:
        f = "{0}.{1}".format(i,j)
        filesrc = f + ".jpg"
        src = path+filesrc
        dst = moveto+filesrc
        shutil.move(src,dst)
        j += 1
        if j > 6:
            i += 1
            j = 1
        if i > 1500:
            break
except for OSError as e:
    pass
```

Comment: Why do you put the whole loop inside of try-except? It's generally a good idea to just surround the part of the code that can fail, in this case shutil.move().

Comment: Your source and target are the same. Are you trying to move **all** files of type jpg from one place to another? Your loop won't process 10_000 files anyway - it would stop after 9_000

Comment: side note: use of `i` and `j` in your code is extremely unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `try-catch` block inside the loop, where the operation might fail.

```py
import os, shutil
path = "I:\\"
moveto = "I:\\"
i = 1
j = 1
while True:
    f = "{0}.{1}".format(i,j)
    filesrc = f + ".jpg"
    src = path+filesrc
    dst = moveto+filesrc
    try:
        shutil.move(src,dst)
    except for OSError as e:
        pass
    j += 1
    if j > 6:
        i += 1
        j = 1
    if i > 1500:
        break
```